# Is O((n^2)*log(n)) greater than O(n^(2.5))?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I know that $O(n^2\times \log(n))$ is greater than $O(n^2)$, but is $O(n^2\times \log(n))$ greater than $O(n^{2.5})$?

Comment: We have a [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth) with plenty of material on this. Happy reading!

Answer (score 16):

In order to compare 2 complexities just calculate a limit of their ratios as below:

$\displaystyle\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2log(n)}{n^2\sqrt{n}} 
   &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log(n)}{\sqrt{n}} 
    = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log(\sqrt{n})^2}{\sqrt{n}}
    = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2log(\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}} \\
    &\underset{\left| k = \sqrt{n} \right|}{=}
      \ \ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2log{(k)}}{k}
    = 2\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{log{(k)}}{k} \\
    &\leq 2\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{ln{(k)}}{k} \\
    &\overset{\ast}{=} 2\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(ln{(k))'}}{k'}
    = 2\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1}
    = 2\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k} \\
   &= 0
\end{align*}$

We use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to simplify calculating a limit for $\frac{\ln(k)}{k}$ at *.

As you can see, $O(n^2\times\log(n))$ is lower than the other.

Answer (score 12):

$O(n^2 \times \log(n))$ is greater than $O(n^2)$ but it is smaller than $O(n^{2 + \epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, however small $\epsilon$ is (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/528009/386794)).

In particular, it is smaller than $O(n^{2.5})$. You're basically comparing the growth of $\log$ and square root.

Answer (score 5):

As $n^{0.5}$ is always greater than $\log(n)$, $O(n^{2.5})= O(n^2 \times n^{0.5})$ is always bigger than $O(n^2 \times \log(n))$. Anyway, you should consider your real algorithm usage scenario to choose one which fits the best.

Comment: Yeah thank you, but sorry, i forgot parentheses on n^2*log(n), it's n^2 multiplied for log(n)

Comment: I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is wrong. $3n$ is always greater than $2n$ and yet $O(3n) = O(2n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Raphael, but your example shows constant differences and is correct, while differences are limited to constants. Here, the difference changes the internal functions completely and mathematically comparable.

Comment: "Here, the difference changes the internal functions completely and mathematically comparable" -- mathematics don't care about whether you change $n$ to $2n$ or $n^2$, per se -- they are different functions. "Greater" has a clear mathematical definition. What you are doing is to explain asymptotics using asymptotics -- that's not useful at all. Instead, the OP needs an explanation _why_ $n \leadsto 2n$ is an "insignificant" change (according to Landau notation) whereas $2 \leadsto n^2$ is not.

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing if you agree that
$$O(n^0.5)>O(log(n))$$
. I have written a short answer, which explains the comparison result simply and implicitly. –

Comment: That expression "$O(\_) > O(\_)$" doesn't make sense. I recommend you revisit the definition of $O$ -- it's a _class of functions_.